# What kind of magic would math correspond to?

Tags: soft-question

Lets pretend for a moment that magic actually exists. Say there is a machine which could turn on your magic "abilities". Say furthermore that proficiency in non-magic skills corresponds to proficiency in certain "schools of magic". What would math correspond to?

I'd like to see actual justifications for answers. For example if we wanted to compare math to an element, we could say "Math corresponds to Earth because it lies at the foundation of science", or we could say "Math corresponds to Air because one can find math in everything".

"Schools of magic" here refers to the schools of magic traditionally present in the Dungeons and Dragons universe.

Comment: @Sally: It's since been edited to remove that.

Comment: This might be a better question for the Role-playing Games SE: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It would be very helpful to give a different example of a non-magical skill n the corresponding school of magic.

Comment: It would be very helpful to give a different example of a different non-magical skill and the corresponding school of magic.